# I can't seem to get my 2 eyes working for Turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

So what am I missing here? I simply need to have 2 eyes that are filled in with the color red. I'm not sure what is missing for the "def eye", but I'm sure that's where I have made a mistake.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

def DCircle(x,y,radius,color):
    t.penup()
    t.setposition(x,y)
    t.pendown()
    t.fillcolor(color)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.color(color)
    t.circle(radius)
    t.end_fill()

def eye(color, radius):
    t.penup()
    t.setposition(-50,40)
    t.pendown()
    t.fillcolor(color)
    t.color(red)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(radius)
    t.end_fill()

def Mickey():
    r = 50
    DCircle(0,0,2*r,'blue')
    DCircle(-135,115,r,'red')
    DCircle(135,115,r,'red')

def Main():
    Mickey()
    turtle.done()
    turtle.bye()
    turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()

Main()
```

Comment: I think this code is working perfectly, what is your expected output, and output you are getting now?

Comment: Well, I'm supposed to have 2 circular eyes that are filled with red. Do you get 2 eyes on the blue face with red fill?

Comment: Oh! You mean inside blue! No outside the blue circle.

Comment: I get the red circular ears. The blue circular face. But I don't get the red circular eyes.

Comment: Yes, inside the blue circle.

Comment: You can [edit] your question from here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

def DCircle(x,y,color,radius):
    t.penup()
    t.setposition(x,y)
    t.pendown()
    t.fillcolor(color)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.color(color)
    t.circle(radius)
    t.end_fill()

def Mickey():
    r = 50
    DCircle(0,0,'blue',2*r)
    DCircle(-50,40,"red",r)
    DCircle(50,40,"red",r)

def Main():
    Mickey()
    turtle.done()
    turtle.bye()
    turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()

Main()
```

You haven't positioned correctly! I think in your code you created `eye` function but never use that, but you don't need that function anyway. We can do anything circular in `DCircle` function.

**Edit :**
You can `Mickey` function this then you will get as you say 2 eyes and 2 ears!

```
def Mickey():
    r = 50
    DCircle(0,0,2*r,'blue')
    DCircle(-135,115,r,'red')
    DCircle(135,115,r,'red')
    DCircle(-50,100,20,"red")
    DCircle(50,100,20,"red")
```

I don't think you need to make that`eye` function!

**What's you are doing wrong in your code :**

1. First thing, you haven't call that eye function, and you are expecting to work. You have to call that function first then only it will work.
2. There is an error in `t.color(red)` you can't write color name like this, color name should always be string!
3. If you have fixed all above wrong things, then also you only get left eye cuz you have hard coded the position of turtle like this `t.setposition(-50,40)`.
4. If you to hard code the eyes then, you have to make 2 function. One for left and second for eye.
5. **Twist :** You don't have to create new functions, you can use `DCircle` function to do all these things, you have already made  dynamic function to make any type of circle then, why you need to make new function and over complicate the things.

Comment: No no, that's not what I was trying to do... the ears need to stay where they are at. I only needed to add the eyes. My thought was it was simply my "def eye" statement.

Comment: It should be 4 red circles total, 2 for the ears, 2 for the eyes. I'm only missing the eyes and I'm trying to figure out why that is...

Comment: Have you mention that in question that you want to make 4 other circle then that big blue?

Comment: I thought I did. It's supposed to be a picture of Mickey Mouse. So 2 ears and 2 eyes. The blue circle is just supposed to be the face essentially. On that blue face should be 2 eyes that are red circles. I thought my "def eye" would work but you said not to use that. So if you look at the original code I pasted and remove the "def eye" section, that's the code I started with. But I can't figure out how to paste new code on a comment again.

Comment: If you can do the same things from single function the why you need to add another function and complicate the right things!

Comment: I had previously tried what you did and add a few lines to Mickey as well but it just gives an error about "bad color argument".

Comment: raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color arguments: %s" % str(color))

Comment: @user16411104 I have explained all the wrong things you are doing in your code. And answer to fix all those as well. Please read those carefully! Carefully!!

Comment: I got it working now. Sometimes I noticed Visual Studio takes some time to start working in between copy/paste of code. Weird behavior. I have to start over with my original code and then start adding back items.

Comment: @user16411104 If you are asking about that then, ask new question. It is worth of new question. And if it solved your issue mark this answer as accepted and give upvote, if you like my effort!